# Выдача нужной строки (mysql group by, having)

Tags: mysql

Доброй ночи!

Допустим у меня есть таблица:

> `start length
> 2 10
> 2 9
> 2 6 
> 3 4
> 3 5
> 3 12
> 3 7`

Я выполняю group by `start` и получаю, например, такие две строки

> `2 6
> 3 7`

Как сделать group by таким образом, чтобы на выводе выдавалась строка с максимальным параметром length:

> `2 10
> 3 12`

Важна именно вся строка (много важных сопутсвующих полей), а не просто max(length).

Answer (score 1):

К сожалению, вчерашний обширный пост исчез....

При большом ( больше чем log2(N) ) кол-ве вариантов start, самым быстрым должен быть этот запрос

```
select * from ( select * from `test` order by `length` desc ) as `t` group by `start`
```

Comment: Да, спасибо, это простое решение очень кстати.

Однако я ещё надеюсь найти какой-то аналог кода для Oracle:

    select start, max(length) keep (dense_rank first order by length desc)
    from t
    group by t.start

Но только для mysql.

Answer (score 0):

Если нужно полностью вывести все строки где `length` максимальное, то:

```
SELECT t.*
FROM table AS t
INNER JOIN
    (
        SELECT start, MAX(length) AS length
        FROM table
        GROUP BY 1
    ) AS gt
ON (gt.start = t.start) AND (gt.length = t.length)
```

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT `table`.`start`,   MAX(`table`.`length`) --тут дописываем другие поля если нада показать их
FROM `table`
GROUP BY  `table`.`start`
```

Comment: читай внимательнее, max(`length`) выдаст тебе максимум в группе, а всю строку выведет последнюю из сгруппированных.