# SQL запрос по выборке

Tags: sql

Выбрать картины по каждому code_style с минимальным price
В code_style хранятся значения(1-20)

**Table:**

```
code_style | name | price
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Было уже [такое](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/45462/%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B0-%D0%BD%D1%83%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B8-mysql-group-by-having?%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B0=1#45837)

```
select *
from (select * from `table` order by `price` asc ) as `t`
group by `code_style`
```

Чуть медленнее, но выводит все записи с мин. стоимостью для каждой категории

```
SELECT * FROM `table`
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT MIN( `price` ) AS `price`, `code_style` FROM `table` GROUP BY `code_style` 
) AS `t`
ON `table`.`code_style` = `t`.`code_style` AND `table`.`price` = `t`.`price`
```

Comment: спасибо, не заметил что такое уже было.

Answer (score 0):

Стандартное решение

```
select * from table t1
where price = (select min(price) from table t2 where t2.code_style = t1.code_style)
```

Comment: Скорость далека от оптимальной.

Comment: В вопросе не было требования к скорости.
В тегах не было указана СУБД.
Я предложил решение, которое будет работать практически под любыми.

Comment: разница в скорость от 100 раз...

Comment: 1. Как меряли?
2. На чем меряли?
У меня, например, SQL Server вообще строит идентичные планы. :-)
А свои способности к оптимизации запросов вы можете проявить на 3-м рейтинговом этапе на sql-ex.ru

Comment: у вас подзапрос выполняется для каждой строки таблицы<br>
на тестовой базе ( 1к записей ) занял 2.5 секунды

Comment: Повторю, что у себя я вижу одинаковые планы для моего запроса и вашего. Бессмысленно сравнивать производительность на разных СУБД с разными схемами и разными данными.